# Route with $id or all data in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, api, codeigniter

I want to get all my data or select with by id, but something is wrong. When I try with route, not work. If i try without route, the select by ID work, and without id have `"Missing argument..."`

```
mysite.com/ws/v1/article - Return all my data (ok) but also a "Missing argument for Articles".

mysite.com/ws/v1/article/6 (6 = id example) Return "The page is not found".
```

**Routes**

```
$route['ws/v1/article'] = "api/articles/getArticle";
```

**Controller**

```
public function getArticle_get($id)
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    // Load Authorization Token Library
    $this->load->library('Authorization_Token');

    /**
     * User Token Validation
     */
    $is_valid_token = $this->authorization_token->validateToken();

    if (!empty($is_valid_token) AND $is_valid_token['status'] === TRUE)
    {
      if (empty($id)){
          $data = $this->db->get("ga845_clientes")->result();
      }else{
          $data = $this->db->get_where("ga845_clientes", ['id' => $id])->row_array();
      }

      $this->response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);

    } else {
        $this->response(['status' => FALSE, 'message' => $is_valid_token['message'] ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you pass the parameters in your api.

```
mysite.com/ws/v1/article/$6
```

To make your parameter optional,

```
$route['ws/v1/article/?(:id)?'] = "api/articles/getArticle/$1";
```

Comment: About route you right! But the "missing argument" still happen.

Comment: try this  $route['ws/v1/article/?(:id)?'] = "api/articles/getArticle/$1";

Comment: Work! Thank you! About "missing argument" I have defined $id = 0 in function.